# how to use specific entry from a URL using requests

Tags: python, dictionary, url, python-requests, yahoo

I have seen a lot of posts on how to use `requests.get(link).json()`. I followed along and I am able to `import` the link but when I try to focus on a specific item with entry such as: `optionchain['ask']`, it gives me an error message.

I use data from this yahoo finance link: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/amd

and would like to import as specific variables the different strike prices, ask and bid. Could anyone please help me with that? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The JSON at the link you posted has multiple levels. To get the ask price you have to call 
`data['optionChain']['result'][0]['quote']['ask']` where `data` is the result from requests.get(link).json()

```
import requests
data = requests.get(r"https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/amd").json()
ask = data['optionChain']['result'][0]['quote']['ask']
```

Comment: I would have, but I need 15 reputation points first. Thanks again I love when things work fine :)